# Mapping a device input or output to an instance of a function block through a config file

Tags: plc, codesys

I'm trying to find a way to map the device inputs and outputs directly to a variable in an instance of a function block.

I know I could solve this with full path mapping through the IDE I/O config, but I want to modify the mapping without using the IDE so I'm looking for a way to map directly via code.

Classic mapping would be done here:
[image: classic mapping]

I will have a file which includes the full path name of the function block instance and comes with the I/O information (if its an input or output, analog or digital, where its connected at the physical plc,...) but how can I apply this information through code not through the IDEs GUI like shown above.

Comment: For TwinCAT I know you can use the [Automation Interface](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tc3_automationinterface/831837579.html?id=7447317642302618429) to do this. For Codesys I don't know unfortunately.

Comment: Quick search around found [Import mapping from csv](https://content.helpme-codesys.com/en/CODESYS%20Development%20System/_cds_cmd_import_io_mapping_csv.html) which seems like it should do what you want if you know all of the appropriate paths.

Comment: It might help if you show an example code of what you are hoping to achieve. If what you want can't be done with normal means, you might be able to do something simmilar using the Script Engine API.

Comment: @SturmGhost I've already done something like this by putting a generic name in the word that contains the IO, and through settings in the HMI I redirected the correct Word to my POUs using a Switch-Case. It would be easier to help if you indicate which PLC and type of IO you are using, if it is a remote, which model... These things may depend on the manufacturer.

Comment: @dwpessoa im using Schneider plc modicon M241.